# Unable to play movie from document directory in iOS

Tags: ios, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsdata, nsdocumentdirectory

I have this function to write NSData to document dictionary -

```
- (void)writeData
{
    NSString *str = @"http://labs.widespace.com/resources/banner/ikea/verkligheten/video.m4v";

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
    NSLog(@"%@",path);
    NSLog(@"About to Write Data");
    NSData* data0 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
    [data0 writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Writting  Data Completed");
}
```

Later i read this data and try to play the video using MPMoviePlayerController, but unfortunately this
does not play-

```
- (void)readData
{
    NSString *str = @"http://labs.widespace.com/resources/banner/ikea/verkligheten/video.m4v";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];    
    NSLog(@"url:%@",url);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL isReacahble = [url checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&error];
    NSLog(@"isReachable :%i,%@",isReacahble,error);

    BOOL fileExist =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];

    if(fileExist)
    {
        NSLog(@"File Exist in path");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NO File Exist");
    }

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    NSLog(@"movie player:%@",moviePlayer);
    [moviePlayer setControlStyle: MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 480)];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;   
    [moviePlayer play];
}
```

When i try to play this it shows following error-

```
2013-01-17 11:21:07.067 VideoCheck[338:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2013-01-17 11:21:07.068 VideoCheck[338:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2013-01-17 11:21:07.090 VideoCheck[338:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2013-01-17 11:21:07.091 VideoCheck[338:907] movie player:<MPMoviePlayerController: 0x21078250>
2013-01-17 11:21:07.093 VideoCheck[338:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2013-01-17 11:21:07.102 VideoCheck[338:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-01-17 11:21:07.113 VideoCheck[338:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
2013-01-17 11:21:07.114 VideoCheck[338:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
2013-01-17 11:21:07.115 VideoCheck[338:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-01-17 11:21:07.121 VideoCheck[338:907] [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
2013-01-17 11:21:07.149 VideoCheck[338:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
```

Can someone please run the code and provide some information about what's happening here??Please someone help me. I am using iOS 6.

Comment: I found the problem, it's totally stupid things, if we use large name with lots of '/', UIKit can't parse data appropriately, and 1 more things to play video with MPMoviePlayer we must need to use some video format extension like .m4v in url path, otherwise MPMoviePlayer won't be able to play it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `wrieData` method, instead of giving `URL` name as file, give only the name of the `video`. Like

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[str lastPathComponent]];
```

and do the same in `readData` method too.